# Scroll view - How to keep the objects in the view

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton, uiswitch

I have a scroll view which has numerous `textfields` and then some `UISwitches` and `UIButtons` followed by more `textfields`.

I have found the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` event and use that to scroll the `textfield` into the view.  But I have not found something similar for the other objects like the `UISwitch` and `UIButton`.

Is there something that does this?  Below is the code I use for the `textfields`:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {  
    [self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:textField];  
} 



- (void)scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:(UIView *)theView {  
    CGFloat viewCenterY = theView.center.y;  
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];  

    CGFloat availableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - _keyboardHeight;    // Remove area covered by keyboard  

    CGFloat y = viewCenterY - availableHeight / 2.0;  
    if (y < 0) {  
        y = 0;  
    }  
    ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(applicationFrame.size.width, applicationFrame.size.height + _keyboardHeight);  
    [ScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:YES];  



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **UIControlEventValueChanged** event.

```
[switchControl addTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: Would I add a reference to all of the UISwitch objects and then have a line like your example for each one? Aso the ScrollViewtoCenter... needs to have the view sent to it.  How would I do that in your example?

Comment: Yes you have to write above code for each UISwitch. And when method scrollViewToCenterOfScreen is called it will get View on which the even was triggered as argument so you can directly use that view for performing any operation.

Comment: Events pass the sender object by default (which matches the signature of your scrollViewToCenterOfScreen method). Simply add the above line for each UISwitch control in your form and everything will work as-is.